# How can I add the bin subdirectory of the specific directory to the PATH to be able to run a software applications from any directory?

Tags: path

I just downloaded a software, [JChem](https://chemaxon.com/products/jchem-engines/), a tool that allows me to create, manage and analyze chemical structures. I run the installer `.sh` script and [the installation guide](https://docs.chemaxon.com/display/docs/Installation+Guide) counsels to add the `bin` subdirectory of the `jchemsuite` directory to `PATH` to be able to run JChem applications from any directory.

I read on a related question how to include all the `bin` subdirectories of subdirectories of a given directory in `$PATH`:

```
for d in /opt/*/bin; do PATH="$PATH:$d"; done
```

I also read about stow but I never used it and I don't know which version to get from the GNU website.

But has far as it is in my `/Download` it would maybe be a security issue.

Therefore, how can I follow their counsel ?

**How can I add the bin subdirectory of the specific directory to the
PATH to be able to run the software applications from any directory.**

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned GNU `stow`...

Using GNU `stow`, you would move the `jchemsuite` directory to somewhere like
`$HOME/local/stow` (so that you have `$HOME/local/stow/jchemsuite`).

Then:

```
cd "$HOME/local/stow"
stow -v jchemsuite
```

Then make sure that `$HOME/local/bin` is in your `PATH` by editing you shell's startup file (usually `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` if you are on Linux):

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/local/bin"
```

In the next new shell session, you would then be able to use the JChem binaries without specifying the full path to them.

To uninstall and delete the binaries of JChem:

```
cd "$HOME/local/stow"
stow -Dv jchemsuite
rm -rf jchemsuite
```

This assumes that JChem actually allows you to move the `jchemsuite` directory (it may refer to it by its original path somewhere in the bowels of the code).  If not, just set `PATH` as

```
 PATH="$PATH:/path/to/JChem/jchemsuite/bin"
```

which is what I assume they *expect* people to do.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using bash, if using another shell, please specify and I will update my example.

open your `.bashrc` file (which should be located in your home folder, i.e. `/home/youruser`)

e.g. `emacs ~/.bashrc`

Then go to the last line and add this:

`export PATH=/path/to/bin:/another/path/to/bin:$PATH`

This way you will add to `PATH` environment variable whatever you want, and you will keep whatever was defaulted in the system.

Please note that for changes to apply you need to log off and then back on (environmental variables are defined upon login, as the `.bashrc` file is "executed" when logging in).

If you want to see what's defined at `PATH`, just do `echo $PATH`

Comment: Thank you ! And how to I found the path to bin of the software I installed ?

Comment: well, that depends on how you installed the software, if you are using a CentOS/RHEL/Fedora like distribution you could do the following
1. get the pacakge name
`yum list ${search_string}\*` please note that `\*` is used as the extended expression operator "anything"
2. query the package `rpm -lq ${package_name}`
anyway, please note that most of the apps may use more than one folder in Linux. E.g. Apache HTTPD uses `/var/www/html` for the sites (the files to be served) but `/etc/httpd` for the web server and vhost configurations.

Comment: I'm on Linux 16.04. hmm ... I only ran the `jchem_unix_18.10.sh` so when I try to query `yum list ${jchem_unix18.10}\*` it gives me a `bad substitution` message back

Comment: Seems that you are using a proprietary app or something else that is not pulled from a public repository. Then try to cat that installation script file and grep for bin, e.g. `cat jchem_unix_18.10.sh | grep "\bin"` I cannot really tell as depending on how the app is installed and who is going to use it, the convention for installation could be different. In most linux systems, any foreign app is normally deployed at `/opt` fodler (which stands for optional). HTH

Comment: The output of the `cat` command is `Binary file (standard input) matches`.

About `/opt` directory, I found a folder called `chemaxon` there I don't know if it is related to `jchem`,

Comment: @Marine1 Software usually comes with installation instructions. Read these and if that does not tell you exactly what you need to do and change, do contact the JChem project about this.

Comment: Also, never add `.` (dot) at the start of you `PATH`. It's a security risk.

Comment: yes, my bad, I typed the wrong thing, I agree with the ```.``` thing